# Checkbox state not toggle. Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use Material UI checkbox component, and try toggle state onCheck, in console state changes but in UI not, the check mark does not toggle. what did I mess.

```
class CheckboxInteractivity extends React.Component {

    state = {
        switched: false,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {checked} = this.props
        if (checked) {
            this.setState({
                switched: true,
            })
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event, switched) => {
        this.setState({switched: !this.state.switched})
    }

    render () {
        const {switched} = this.state

        return <Checkbox
            label="Label"
            checked={switched}
            onCheck={this.handleChange}
            {...this.props}
                />
    }
}

CheckboxInteractivity.propTypes = {
    checked: PropTypes.bool,
}

export default CheckboxInteractivity
```

components

```
<CheckboxInteractivity /> 
//working correctly
<CheckboxInteractivity checked/>
//not working
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason why it is not working with second case is:

```
return <Checkbox
            label="Label"
            checked={switched}
            onCheck={this.handleChange}
            {...this.props}
       />
```

Will become:

```
return <Checkbox
            label="Label"
            checked={switched}
            onCheck={this.handleChange}

            checked={true}                     //here

       />
```

You are using two `checked` property and second will make the **checkbox checked true** always irrespective of the `state` variable that's why. Remove `{...this.props}` it will work as expected.

Why it is working in first case is, you are not passing the `checked` so `checkbox` will find only one checked key and it will render the component on the basis of that.

Here `{...this.props}` is not required because you are already storing the value in `state`.

**Suggestion:**

Instead of setting the `props` value in `state` in `componentWillMount` lifecycle method set that in `constructor` only, like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        switched: props.checked || false,
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Let's say, you are passing many values in `props` and few values you want to override in component, so what you need to do here is, first apply all the `props` properties, then define the other properties. By this way, component properties will override the `props` properties.

Like this:

```
return <Checkbox
            {...this.props}                //first apply props values then other
            label="Label"
            checked={switched}
            onCheck={this.handleChange}                
       />
```

Comment: Only one issue in case if I want to try to add props disable I need {...this.props}, because depends on this props I set styles <CheckboxInteractivity checked/>

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro check the updated answer, update section. You just need to apply the `props` values first then the other values, ordering will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when using two Mui Checkboxes which values depends on each other.

I had "parent state" which I tried to use within both of the checkboxes. I provided this state using context provider.

### Solution

I solved the problem by initializing separate state `const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)` inside both of the checkbox components. I did this to prevent "uncontrolled" component initialization.

To bind "checked" states to parent state, I defined a simple `useEffect()` function.

Like this:

```
export const DrugUsageStartCheckBox = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    // parent state can be used only if component is wrapped to context provider.
    const {state, dispatch} = useParentState();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(state.checked)
    }, [state.checked])

    return (
            <Checkbox
                id={'my-checkbox'}
                checked={checked}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    dispatch({type: "toggleChecked"})
                }}
    ...
```